# How to find document name in jupyter notebook using code in a script?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyterhub

I want to get the filename of the notebook created in Jupyter by writing code in a python file and import it in notebook and then click on Run. This should give me the name of file in a variable which I can print.

Suppose notebook name in Jupyter is Get_File_Name.ipynb So I want to store Get_File_Name in a variable.

Tried using javascript magic cell from python code in a file and import that python file in notebook.

Tried using widgets to insert filename in a widget. Both not working

Write python code in file print_filename.py

```py
from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()

ipython.run_cell_magic('javascript', '','IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(\'nb_name = "\' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + \'"\')')
print(nb_name)
```

In Jupyter notebook run the using

`import print_filename`

If I print nb_name in different paragraph, I am able to fetch it. But in same paragraph, error is 
But error comes:

````
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5fa7a942367b> in <module>
----> 1 import print_filename

~/print_filename.py in <module>
      2 ipython = get_ipython()
      3 ipython.run_cell_magic('javascript', '','IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(\'nb_name = "\' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + \'"\')')
----> 4 print(nb_name)

NameError: name 'nb_name' is not defined```


Tried other way:

```python

from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()

ipython.run_cell_magic('javascript', '','IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(\'nb_name = "\' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + \'"\')')
````

```
import print_filename
print(nb_name)
```

Same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget

Here is the code

```py
import jp_proxy_widget

nb_name = None

def save_name(name):
    global nb_name
    nb_name = name

get_name = jp_proxy_widget.JSProxyWidget()
get_name.js_init("""
var name = IPython.notebook.notebook_name;
element.html("The name of the notebook is" + name);
save_name(name);
""", save_name=save_name)
get_name
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]