# Can I execute Javascript code in a jupyter notebook that highlights things in the output and not using the notebook cells?

Tags: javascript, jupyter

I have this code which iterates over all cells and highlights something like '100MB' in the output of the cells. I can execute it in the firefox console. But it should be done automatically when I run the code in the cells.

I tried executing it with glue or putting the code in a js file and then refer to it in the metadata of the cells with the embed_html tag. But these methods are not designed for that I think.

Is there another way to execute the javascript code?

Comment: I would think that for JupyterLab, something related to the ability to make tours,  see  [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/jupyterlab-tour#jupyterlab-tour), or possibly [ipylab](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab) might offer a direction to go that isn't just making an extension yourself. In the older classic interface, I note there are some annotation tools that may work. I also remember something about Hypothes.is being integrated with Jupyter in some way, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/annotating-jupyter-notebooks/2079/7). ...

Comment: <continued>  I don't see much firm but the directions or approaches might offer something. Keep in mind the classic notebook isn't going to be as it is much longer and you'll want to move towards JupyterLab-workable solutions as the new single-document centric offering, see [here](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html).

Comment: For more general hooking javascript to Jupyter, see [an examplerhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58879959/8508004) with [jp_proxy_widget](https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget). Also there are magic commands (see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_cell_magic_functions.htm) or [here](https://medium.com/@shouke.wei/how-to-run-javascript-in-jupyter-notebook-325a86402f2f)) and `IPython.notebook.kernel.execute()`. And also see [Embedding JavaScript in a Jupyter notebook](https://til.simonwillison.net/jupyter/javascript-in-a-jupyter-notebook).